# Why can only gravitons or gravity pass through to other membranes?

Tags: string

String Theory suggests that only gravity and no there type of forces like strong,weak or em can leave a particular membrane and pass through to others.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the question here is. String theory *can* have space-filling gauge fields that impart forces akin to electromagnetism between membranes. Please give a reference for the claim that "only gravity can pass through membranes".

Answer (score 3):

The idea is that gravitons are represented by excitations of closed strings, while the other particles are represented by excitations of open strings. An open string has its ends pinned to the brane so it cannot migrate between different branes, however a closed string has no ends and is therefore free to move between branes.